# Translating sentences into quantified logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Consider two functions $f : A → B$ and $g : A → B$. Translate each of the following statements
into formal notation using quantificational logic

(a) Every output generated by $f$ is also generated by $g$
$$\forall x \forall y \forall z (f(x)=y=g(x)=z⇒y=z) $$

(b) $f$ is surjective

$$\forall x\in A \forall y \in B(f(x)=f(y) ⇒ x=y)$$

These were my attemps  at translation. If I am off please let me know why thank you.

Comment: Your predicate for (a) is a tautology: as a sample you can see that for $A=B=\Bbb R$, $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t+1$ the following holds $$\forall x, \forall y,\forall z ((x=y\land y=x+1\land x+1=z)\Rightarrow y=z)$$ Therefore it cannot be right. Your (b) raises the fundamental question of what $f(x)=f(y)$ means for $y\in B$, seeing as the attentive reader should be under the impression that $f(t)$ only makes sense for $t\in A$.

Comment: Anyways, one must wonder why those guys bothered to make *two* quantifiers when apparently you seem particularly adamant in using just $\forall$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) $\forall x \in A \; \exists y \in A \; f(x) = g(y)$

(b) $\forall y \in B \; \exists x \in A \; f(x) = y$